# Next Js 14 file structure

Tags: next.js

I am using Next 14 with src directory. My current directory structure is:
`/src/app/page.tsx`.
What will be the proper structure to arrange pages and api directory in this?

I added the pages directory inside the app as
`src/app/pages/staff/page.tsx`
And for api I added
`src/app/pages/api/route.tsx`
But I am facing an issue with api routes as the res.send is not a function so it means that this might not be the correct structure for the api directory.

Answer (score 3):

In Next 14, your pages will all be in the app directory, i.e. /src/app/{page name}/page.tsx - there is no pages directory anymore.

For your APIs, put them in '/src/app/api/{route name}/route.ts
You can then access your route by going to 'http://{your domain}/api/{your route name}

(Note the file is ts, as we aren't including jsx.)

A practical example, if you are on localhost:3000 and your route name is 'content' is:

file: /src/app/api/content/route.ts

route: 'http://localhost:3000/api/content'